# How to disable button after clicked on discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

### Discord.js v12 Disable Buttons Function

---

how do I disable a button on discord.js after it is clicked?
I tried using the collector.on function, since that seems to do it but I can't make it work with my code and I know, I didn't copy-paste but I can't seem to work it out and its stressing me a lot, i looked through all the web to get answers but nothing anywhere. the discord-buttons js guide just disappeared. Well you've come to the right place you can simply do the following below its explained and can really help you .

---

So because the last answer was not right but had some correct formats
this is what you wanna do. The code is explained the best i can below

---

The Code:

```
// After you have made your buttons and the embed you then need to do
// You can do this method a lot of times just make sure to add a cooldown.
// You can also do the same with the MessageActionRow() constructor
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor('red').setDescription('click the below buttons').setTimestamp()
const dbutton = new MessageButton().setStyle('blurple').setID('lol').setLabel('disabled button').setDisabled(true).setEmoji('')
const button = new MessageButton().setStyle('blurple').setID('yes').setLabel('enabled button').setEmoji('')
const after = await message.channel.send({ embed: embed, components: [button] })

client.on("clickButton", async (button) => {
if (button.id === "yes") {
message.channel.send({ content: "you clicked the first button" })
after.edit({ embed: embed, components: [dbutton] })
} 
button.reply.defer();
});
```

---

***The above `embed:` and `components:` are supported in v12.***
***I hope this helped you with further questions***

Comment: By the way, v12 will no longer work from April on, so update your bot as soon as possible.

Comment: yeah I've already started it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessageButton class has a "setDisabled" method that you can set to true.

When done, it won't automatically disable it. You need to edit the embed, passing the components again.

```
     const button11 = 

    const row = new MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
             new MessageButton()
                 .setStyle('green')
                 .setID('yes')
                 .setLabel('Lock')
                 .setEmoji('')
         )

    const supportembedy = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                              .set(....)

    let botMsg = await channel.send(supportembedy, row);

    const filter = i => ((i.customId === "yes") || (i.customId === "no")) && i.user.id === message.author.id 
    const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({filter, time: 15000})

    collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
        if (i.customId === 'yes') {
            row[0].setDisabled(true)
            // first way
            botMsg.edit({ embeds: [supportembedy], components: [row] })
            //second way
            i.update({ embeds: [supportembedy], components: [row] })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sure, let me write one and then I will edit my answer

Comment: The function interaction.channel.createMessageComponentColllector does not work in v12 this is a v13 collector function. in v12 you must use the createButtonCollector function ex. botMsg.createButtonCollector({filter, time/idle: 3000})

Comment: Right, you can always adapt it. Please mark as accepted answer if it solved your problem